# How can I do to create a space between Or and my link?

Tags: html

I have this code :

```
Or 
<a href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
   start your trial
</a>
```

which produces this :

[image: The result]

But I would like to have a space between Or and my link...

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Just add css margin to the `a` element, you could do this easily with inline;

```html
Or 
<a style="margin:10px;" href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
   start your trial
</a>
```

or with a selector; (I'm using id)

```css
#link {
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
Or 
<a id="link" href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
   start your trial
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Or&nbsp; 
<a href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
   start your trial
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a margin:

```
Or 
<a href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500" style = "margin-left: 2px">
start your trial
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` between `Or` and your `<a>` tag, such as:

```
Or &nbsp;
<a href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
   start your trial
</a>
```

You can also use:

- `&nbsp;` - for 1 space
- `&ensp;` - for 2 spaces
- `&emsp;` - for 4 spaces